# group elements in a list of numbers according to a threshold in R

Tags: r

suppose i have a list of number:

```
numbers = c(1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 2, 3, 7, 6)
```

and a threshold

```
threshold = 6
```

I want to group the elements in the number list according to the threshold -- summing up the elements until you reach/over the threshold. Save the index of the first element of each group, so the desired output is:

```
1, 4, 5, 8, 9
```

1 because it's the start

4 because 1+2+5 = 8 > 6 and this include 3 elements

it is similar to this post [Sum list of numbers until threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34224591/sum-list-of-numbers-until-threshold) but we want to keep adding until we reach the end of the list.

Comment: @PKumar omg, you're right! edited

Comment: @RonakShah correctly! my bad!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional cumsum with reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531568/conditional-cumsum-with-reset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `cumsumbinning` from the package `MESS` :

```
numbers = c(1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 2, 3, 7, 6)
threshold = 6
which(!duplicated(MESS::cumsumbinning(numbers, threshold - 1, cutwhenpassed=TRUE), fromLast = TRUE))
#[1] 3 4 7 8 9
```

If you want the first element in the group.

```
which(!duplicated(MESS::cumsumbinning(numbers, threshold - 1, cutwhenpassed=TRUE)))
#[1] 1 4 5 8 9
```

---

`cumsumbinning` with `cutwhenpassed=TRUE` creates a new group whenever the value passes the `threshold` value hence I used `threshold - 1`.

```
MESS::cumsumbinning(numbers, threshold - 1, cutwhenpassed=TRUE)
#[1] 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 4 5
```

Comment: is there another way to do this without the MESS packages? I keep getting errors when downloading the MESS packages.

Comment: Another way I can think of is messy loops. What is the issue that you are facing downloading the package? I installed it myself while trying to answer this question and I could download it without any problem using `install.packages('MESS')`

Comment: I am getting lots of errors like `ERROR: dependencies 'glmnet', 'kinship2' are not available for package 'MESS'`

Comment: I think the main problem is this line `cannot find -lgfortran`

Answer (score 1):

I think this will also serve the purpose

```
library(purrr)
setdiff(which(accumulate(numbers, ~ifelse(.x + .y <  6, .y + .x, 0)) ==0), which(numbers == 0))

#check on new vector numbers
numbers = c(1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 2, 3, 7, 6, 0, 2, 3, 7, 1, 2)

setdiff(which(accumulate(numbers, ~ifelse(.x + .y <  6, .y + .x, 0)) ==0), which(numbers == 0))
[1]  3  4  7  8  9 13
```